# Potential employer is not disclosing any information about themselves without references

Tags: references, employment-agreement

I applied to a job via craigslist post. Person contacted me and asked a few qualification questions. My email disclosed my website, and resume and Linkedin.

They then proceeded to ask me for job references. I said I would like to learn more about the company and their website and location and they refused to provide any info by stating they can't provide any info until I give them references. To add to the matter, their email is company_name@gmail.com, the email did not contain persons name or signature or anything. Is that a normal practice or should I be wary in my proceedings?

Comment: Run! Run like the wind!

Comment: That just screams "SCAM!" to me

Comment: This is a bottom-feeder recruiter, at best.  An identity thief, at worst.

Comment: Yup.  I can't think of any possible scenario that reasonably explains this other than this "job" being a front for somebody who wants to get your references.  Probably some unscrupulous recruiter.  Or worse.  Do *not* give them anything.

Comment: yeah upon further investigation i found out that it is a front of some sort as they have spammed many job websites with various emails as a carpet cleaning business which was ok with paying a substantial salary to a web designer hahaha thank you all for the info

Comment: SCAM ALERT!  Run like HELL!

Comment: Why look for a job on craigslist then give someone your LinkedIn name? Just use LinkedIn. Much easier to weed out the scams and other unsavory folk that way.

Comment: Weird enough, a few weeks ago I stumbled upon one that demanded photos or scans of my University diploma (?) instead of references. Straight to the bin.

Comment: I'd like to post a gif of Gandalf in Moria when they find the Balrog *"Fly,..."*, but not sure how many downvotes it'd get.

Comment: You would get an upvote from me. Go for it!

Answer (score 104, accepted):

Don't do it!  This is a recruiter looking to get you to provide managerial references.  You'll never hear from that person again, and they'll be plugging your references for new business.

Old scam.

Comment: I think you're being optimistic in thinking this is even a recruiter.

Comment: Information on a resume is pretty generic and useless to a marketer without some demographics.  But phone numbers to hiring managers are GOLDEN! :)

Comment: Right, but phone numbers and job references are valuable to someone trying to open a store credit card in your name and buy a large screen TV.

Comment: Not without an SSN.

Comment: A colleague responded: "Sure! Here is my current manager's phone number." Then gave them the phone number to the local Sheriff's Department. :)

Comment: @codenoire I did some consulting work for the fraud department of a major credit card company. SSN is trivially easy to obtain if you have other details such as phone numbers and employment history.

Comment: @LaconicDroid: Any chance you could tell us how it's so trivial? (I mean just a basic overview... I'm not asking for a tutorial on how to steal SSNs.) I'm asking because I've heard that a lot and I know that if you e.g. buy a home then your SSN becomes public record, but what if I haven't bought a home? Is it still trivial? Is it still public record? Or is it done through social engineering? How?

Answer (score 51):

Yes it is normal practice for meeting a creep.  At worst they might ask for pictures and if you like leather or being tied up.

At best they are a fishy company with little funding and pay.  In the middle they might just be skimming for contacts.

**Verdict:  Don't.  Ignore future contact unless you just feel like messing with them with fake info.**

(you can give them a series of email address and fake people to see what things these people get in the future)

Comment: I like the idea of providing fake contact information and faking being your own references to see what happens to them.

Comment: Or, create a few e-mail accounts for the 'references' and see what comes in.